# How to prevent apt-get/aptitude keeping a cache

Tags: apt, aptitude, apt-cacher-ng

I have installed [Apt-Cacher NG](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) to provide a cache of packages for several machines. I therefore see no point in having aptitude/apt-get keeping their own (second) cache in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. I realise I can empty this cache with `sudo apt-get clean`, but is there some way of configuring apt-get to automatically clean the cache when an install has completed?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as I use many LXC to experiment and to keep my personal computer clean. One of those LXC is my apt-cacher-ng, but now I would like to prevent all other instances (including the "real" one) to keep an archives chace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation you can add a config file to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` named `no-cache` containing `Dir::Cache "";` and `Dir::Cache::archives "";` according to manual of `apt.conf`. There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/937951) report raising issues with this method, and I don't recommend it.

There is one remaining method according to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=564301) tutorial:

```
echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/bin/rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb || true";};' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/clean
```

This will carry out an `rm` command just before apt quits.

Comment: I found just setting the cache path to an empty path gave an error when running apt: ``Archives directory archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)``. The solution to this error was to also set ``Dir::Cache::archives`` to an empty path. I've updated your answer to include this (assuming somebody with higher rep approves the edit).

Comment: Actually, setting these to blank paths doesn't work. I did so, and then installed and removed a package. Going to install it again I got ``Need to get 0 B/21.9 MB of archives`` indicating the presence of a cached version. Looking around it turns out they were cached in the root of the filesystem... not exactly what I wanted! Unless we're both reading the manpage for apt.conf wrong, either the manpage is wrong or there is a bug. I think I'll stick with the second method.

Comment: I've reported the `Dir::Cache::Archive "";` bug at  https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/937951. When you've set that, **do not run `apt-get clean`** as it'll remove all files in the root directory (`/`).

Comment: According to the bug, `Dir::Cache::Archive` is the wrong configuration var; this should be `Dir::Cache::{src,}pkgcache`.

Comment: Has this bug been fixed in a later version?

Comment: I confirm that Ubuntu 14.04, year 2016, still has the same problem. Tested on a container, and the root fills with the packages. Dir::Cache::Archive is not ignored.

Comment: Reopened the bug. Feel free to chime in. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/937951

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, just now: setting both entries (Dir::Cache + ::Archive) to "" works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "false";' \
      > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01disable-cache
```

For more details, see: https://superuser.com/questions/1405001/why-does-apt-do-not-store-downloaded-packages-anymore

Answer (score -2):

I think that what you are looking for is:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ cat 04autoclean
APT::Clean-Installed "true";
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$
```

Comment: That command does not *change* anything--it just shows the contents of `04autoclean` (when run in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory). Are you saying Blair should *change* the contents of `04autoclean` so that `APT::Clean-Installed` is set to `"true"`?

Comment: This will only control how `apt-get autoclean` behaves. From apt-get(8): "The configuration option APT::Clean-Installed will prevent
           installed packages from being erased if it is set to off."