# How can I configure apt-get to clean automatically after every install

Tags: apt

Is there any way do `apt-get clean` after `apt-get install` automatically, like in other distros?

Comment: Thanks to @Braiam I found a bug in Ubuntu and I'll report it.
In Debian Braiam's solution work fine.

Comment: related: [How do I free up disk space?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5980)

Comment: @TiagoCarrondo Can you share the bug link please?

Comment: In Xenial all my machines clean themselves. I don't know where this is configured but it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to add it at the apt configurations files. Just run:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DSELECT::Clean "always";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99AutomaticClean"
```

This will trigger automatic clean each time you do `upgrade`.

Lets explain this entry, from the man page:

> `Clean`
>
> Cache Clean mode; this value may be one of always, prompt, auto,
>              pre-auto and never.  always and prompt will remove all packages
>              from the cache after upgrading, prompt (the default) does so
>              conditionally.  auto removes only those packages which are no
>              longer downloadable (replaced with a new version for instance).
>              pre-auto performs this action before downloading new packages.

More info:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linux.debian.user/aK2jvfL_tuw/rUd6i6bd4YQJ

Comment: I guess it should need a semicolon at the end `;`! and therefore it should be `sudo sh -c "echo 'APT::Get::Clean=always;' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99AutomaticClean"`

Comment: @Braiam I've tried it and it doesn't work. I even tried APT::Get::Clean "always" like in other files but no luck. any clue?

Comment: @Braiam no luck

Comment: @TiagoCarrondo how about now? [This usenet message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linux.debian.user/aK2jvfL_tuw/rUd6i6bd4YQJ) says that is the winner.

Comment: I've tried that already after your first post. Going to change file location... wait

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11928/discussion-between-tiago-carrondo-and-braiam)

Comment: Still not working, there's a bug

Comment: [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/169736) :(

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way (that I know of) to achieve the desired effect here is with the "keep-downloaded-packages" option:

1. Create a new apt config file, e.g.

> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom-conf

2. Add the following to the file.

```
# Remove downloaded .deb files after installation by apt-get
APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "false";
```

Starting the file name with '99' means this config file is read last (and will overwrite any other configuration). Then by setting the 'keep-downloaded-packages' option BOOL value to false, **apt-get** will automatically delete a packages *.deb file from the /var/cache/apt/archives/* directory, immediately after installation (just like 'apt clean').

Note that **apt** itself uses a separate binary directive for the same option, and per [this](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/1.8.2/debian/NEWS#L109) apt NEWS entry, since Nov 2016 (so at least Debian 9 (Stretch)) this has been set to "false" by default. If (for whatever reason) this is not the case for your system, you can append the below to your config file.

```
# Remove downloaded .deb files after installation by apt
Binary::apt::APT::keep-downloaded-packages "false";
```

NOTE: I cannot speak to other desktop environments, but KDE Plasma's **Discover** software center is not affected by either of these options, and so any package installations or upgrades conducted through Discover will keep the cached .deb files, and you will need to run `apt clean` to remove these.

For a convenient index of all apt configuration directives/options, open "/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz OR JUST configure-index (in later versions)".

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script!

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/aptinstaller
```

Inside this file type:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install $1
sudo apt-get -y autoclean
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
```

Save and exit from `nano` and type:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/aptinstaller
```

Now everytime you would type

```
sudo aptinstaller <package-name>
```

It would install and then clean.

Comment: I prefer an option, but sound like a preety good plan B, thx

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/` seems more correct.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround, though not a real solution, is to set the archives directory to `/tmp`. It won't be cleaned automatically after an install but it will be cleaned on reboot.

I created `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99clean` and added:

```
Dir::Cache::archives /tmp;
```

Alternatively you could mount `/var/cache/apt/archives` using `tmpfs`, though that will obviously use up RAM and I wouldn't recommend that option.

In `/etc/fstab`, for example:

```
tmpfs /var/cache/apt/archives tmpfs size=128m,mode=755 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A hack appears to be adding the following to e.g. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/clean` ([via](https://askubuntu.com/a/81211/169)):

```
DPkg::Post-Invoke {"/bin/rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb || true";};
```

This will clear the cache automatically after dpkg has been invoked by apt.

This does not clean the cache after `apt-get update` though, the hook `APT::Update::Post-Invoke` might be used for this.

The best method still appears to be calling `apt-get clean` / `aptitude clean` manually.