# Undo automatic apt-get clean

Tags: apt, google-chrome, chromium, cleanup

Researching ways to keep my system slim I came across this post: [How can I configure apt-get to clean automatically after every install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389728/how-can-i-configure-apt-get-to-clean-automatically-after-every-install)

Following the suggestion I did:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DSELECT::Clean "always";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99AutomaticClean"
```

I'm not 100% sure about the timeline, but about at that time chromium kept asking me to sign into all my accounts and didn't remember my choices anymore, e. g. acknowledging a website using cookies. So that command above might erase chromiums cache, is that it?

Now I removed chromium and am using google-chrome, but that didn't help.

So A) Do you think the action above is the reason for my problems? and more importantly B) How do I undo this?

*I initially forgot to mention I already went `gksudo nautilus` and deleted `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99AutomaticClean`, but it didn't show up in `gksudo nautilus`' trash, so I suppose it is still available to be called on.

Comment: Hmm, see if this helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/822804/after-rebooting-i-need-to-log-in-each-time-in-chrome

Comment: No, it's not available to be called on. And just don't use `dselect`. It's highly undocumented. From it's [manpage](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/dselect/) ___The  dselect  package  selection interface is confusing to some new users.  Reportedly, it
       even makes seasoned kernel developers cry.___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that the two issues are related since Apt's cleaning doesn't affect installed packages at all. In fact it only affects the local cache of downloaded package files.

Nonetheless you can revert the Apt setting if you remove or comment out the line

```
DSELECT::Clean "always";
```

from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99AutomaticClean`. You can also remove the file altogether if it doesn't contain any other useful entries.